# Strange border in Wordpress update 4.1

Tags: wordpress, border, media-player

I've just updated wordpress to 4.1, but now it makes this strange dotted border in firefox, when I click a media element.

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zp4dS.png
Link: tobiassorensen.dk/stemme

Can I use css to remove this, and how?? I have tried several things...

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely caused by Javascript changes in the 4.1 update.

As a workaround, targeting the element with {outline-style: none;} should remove the outlines but be aware that the outlines are there for accessibility reasons.